# Sh command inside Groovy Jenkins script

Tags: shell, groovy

I have shell script which creates link.txt file. 
the link.txt file created in some server (lets called it 'jacoco server').

now , in Groovy script in Jenkins pipeline job , 
im trying to get this file content while doing ssh to the server by the following:

**sh** "/usr/bin/sshpass -p passJac1 **ssh** -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${JACOCO_URL} \"**link=cat ${WORKING_DIR}/jacoco_link/link.txt**\""

pls ignore all the rest, and focus on this line:

```
link=cat ${WORKING_DIR}/jacoco_link/link.txt\
```

i've tried several options to get the link.txt content and save it in link variable, but the pipeline job is failing with different errors for syntax.

ive also tried by the following command

```
link=$(<$WORKING_DIR/jacoco_link/link.txt)
```

but the pipeline job failed again ("wasnt accept to get the <").

please advice

Comment: Hi, correct me if I'm wrong. You must be wanting `link=$(cat $WORKING_DIR/jacoco_link/link.txt)`, don't you?

Comment: Yuiry, thnx for your suggestion, but groovy dosent like it, and mark it as wrong syntax with the following message:

    "illegal string body character after dollar sign;
     solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value 
     expression "${5}".

Comment: Eli, I see. My second guess will be that $WORKING_DIR is evaluated on local machine, and that path is does not exist on the remote machine. If I were you, I would try to manually specify the correct full path to link.txt. And if that helps, I would find out a way to make $WORKING_DIR evaluate in remote context, rather than in local.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is

```
link=`cat ${WORKING_DIR}/whatever`
```

with the backticks.  You don't want your like to be "cat whatever", but rather the result of executing that.